# how to correctly end a regex url match

Tags: c++, regex

I've been working on a url parser but I'm having some trouble getting the ending correct

```
sregex rex = sregex::compile("((?:ftp|http|https)://)([^<>\\s/]+/+[^\\s\"<>]+([^)\\s\\\"<>$]*[\\)$]*))", sregex::icase );
```

I want to NOT allow a single `)` at the end of the string if it is not preceded by a forward-slash( `\` ).  It also can't end with a `"`, `\` `<`, `>` or a whitespace. My effort to do that is:

```
 ([^)\\s\\\"<>$]*[\\)$]*)
```

How do I write it correctly?

Comment: btw: there are many flavours of regexes, it might be useful to mention which you use. Also you might want to rethink if "parser" and "regex" do really fit together...

Comment: @PlasmaHH Why shouldn't it fit together? (Just asking, not that I'm sure it fits)

Comment: It's not clear to me: when you say you don't want to allow a single ) at the end of the string, do you mean an unmatched ).  (As written, I'd understand that )) is fine, but not ).  But that doesn't really seem likely.  If you do mean unmatched: it can't be done with a regular expression.

Comment: if it's a single ), it shouldn't be allowed, if it's )), it should only match a single ), and if it's \\) ,  it should be allowed

Comment: Can you share a couple examples of urls (or characters in urls) that should not be included?

Comment: not allowed - "http://example.com)" allowed - "http://example.com\\)" allowed but should only match one ) - "http://example.com))" allowed but should only match one ) - "http://example.com\\))"

Comment: You should not try to do this unless you check that the url is actually wrong.
For exemple, this url is perfectly valid : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cairo_%28disambiguation%29

Comment: It is actually wrong, that's why I want to do this

Comment: @leemes: because while regexes might be nice for quickly matching stuff and/or extracting something from some text, they often are not powerful enough to resemble the exact syntax the format you have at hand will represent, especially when it can be represented in alternative ways.

Comment: I think I'll just substr it, thanks

Comment: @PlasmaHH Hmm... Still not sure why it isn't a good idea to use regex for tokenization. Of course, there is more logic required apart from a regex matcher. But I personally can't think of a parser *without* using regex. (We can do it, but I think it will be much more complicated when not using regex.)

Answer (score 0):

You want to

- Allow strings which might end with \), )), )))
- Deny stings which end with ", \, <, >, whitespace, or )
- All other strings would be ok

That last close paran needs to be included in the deny characters so that if the string ends with ) it can be found correctly

I tried this in powershell and it works as expected.

```
clear

foreach ($String in @("", "abc", "abc\)", "abc>", "abc<", "abc\", "abc""", "abc)", "abc))", "abc)))", "abc ", "abc`t")) {
    if ( $String -match '((?<!(["\\<>)]|\s))$)|((?<=\\|\){1,})\)$)' )  {
        Write-Host "'$String' is good"

        } else {
        Write-Host "'$String' is bad"
        } # end if
    } # next string
```

I'm using two regex lookbehinds separated by an "or" pipe

```
((?<!(["\\<>)]|\s))$)
```

verifies a denied character is not at the end of the string

```
((?<=\\|\){1,})\)$)
```

if the last character is a ) then all it should be preceded by a \ or one or more )

This small routine yields the following output:

```
'' is good
'abc' is good
'abc\)' is good
'abc>' is bad
'abc<' is bad
'abc\' is bad
'abc"' is bad
'abc)' is bad
'abc))' is good
'abc)))' is good
'abc ' is bad
'abc    ' is bad
```